# ASP .NET: Thread.CurrentPrincipal is lost when customErrors contains redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"

Tags: asp.net, custom-errors

I setup my custom principal in one of the modules that handles Authentication_Request. Then I set it HttpContext.User. That sets my HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Now when an error occurs and customErrors section contains "ResponseRewrite", Thread.CurrentPrincipal is reset to generic principal on my ASPX error page., but my HttpContext.User still contains my custom principal. This does not happen if customErrors section contains "ResponseRedirect". Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Is this tagged properly, doesn't sound like an ASP question.  ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the server is spinning up a separate thread to execute the error page. You might be able to reset it (Thread.CurrentPrincipal) by putting the following into your Global.asax.

```
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
  }
```

This line will insure that both are in sync on each request to your application.